# Грамматическая основа придаточного предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Какую основу надо выделить в придаточном предложении:

> Доктор Кох, в обязанности которого входило лечить обывателей небольшого городка, сидел за перегородкой, никого к себе не подпускал и сам не выходил навстречу.

Comment: Может ли кто-нибудь из местных обывателей подсказать недорогой электронный адрес, где тихо обретается всеобъемлющая монография о русской грамматической основе, с подробным рассказом обо всех удивительных примерах столь популярного сабжа? На всю оставшуюся жизнь я был бы обеспечен нескушным чтением! Спасибо)))

Answer (score 2):

..., в обязанности которого входило лечить обывателей небольшого городка, ...
Лечить-подлежащее, входило в обязанности - сказуемое.

Answer (score 2):

Под словом "лечить" подразумевается слово "лечение". Оно является подлежащим. Сказуемое "входило в обязанности"

Comment: Да, я тоже шла таким путем и выделила такую основу, но засомневалась. Спасибо.